# TextFormField validators get triggered all at once

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and have made a form app that checks validations and disables the 'save' button if the validators are showing. But the problem is that even though I have set the autovalidateMode parameter to AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction for every individual textFormField, all the validators get triggered at once. Here's the problem:

Problematic o/p:

[image]

Desired o/p:

[image]

Here's the minimum reproducible code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StudentInfoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const StudentInfoScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<StudentInfoScreen> createState() => _StudentInfoScreenState();
}

class _StudentInfoScreenState extends State<StudentInfoScreen> {
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController rNoController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController stdController = TextEditingController();

  String validator = 'Field cannot be empty';
  bool isButtonDisabled = true;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    rNoController.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
    stdController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void validateInputs() {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        isButtonDisabled = false;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isButtonDisabled = true;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Details'),
        elevation: 3,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
        },
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
            child: Form(
              key: formKey,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    controller: rNoController,
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    onChanged: (_) {
                      validateInputs();
                    },
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                        return null;
                      }
                      return validator;
                    },
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: nameController,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      onChanged: (_) {
                        validateInputs();
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                          return null;
                        }
                        return validator;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: stdController,
                      autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                      onChanged: (_) {
                        validateInputs();
                      },
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value!.isNotEmpty) {
                          return null;
                        }
                        return validator;
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: (isButtonDisabled) ? null : () {},
                        child: const Text('Save'),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am running the code on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering `validateInputs` in your `onChanged` callbacks inside your `TextFormField`s.

Your `validateInputs` function calls `formKey.currentState!.validate()`, which validates the whole form on each key stroke.

Remove this logic from `onChanged` and you should be fine.

```dart
...
onChanged: (_) {
  validateInputs();  // remove this
},
...
```

Comment: That logic is necessary to keep the 'Save' button disabled until the user has filled the form completely without any errors. Kindly suggest a logic that I can use in its place if the solution is to remove validateInputs() function.